# Regex to Trim cobination of spaves and line breaks from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a string, and I want to trim all the leading and trailing combination of space and < br />.
If the string is

> "< br /> < br />< br />< br /> < br /> < br /> Hello < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> 
> "

I must get Hello.
I unsuccessfully tried:

```
string = string.replace(/(<br \/>)+$| +$/g,'').replace(/^(<br \/>)+|^ +/g,'')
```

Comment: I'm convinced both answers certainly work, but as no one explains you why your regex don't work, here's the explanation: you used the caret `^` and the dollar `$` in the wrong place. So instead of saying, eg, `<br />` or `whitespace` till the end of the string, you say `<br />` till the end of the string OR `whitespace` till the end of the string (and both won't work of course). Factor your expression: `/(<br \/>)+$| +$/` => `/(<br \/>| )+$/`.

Comment: Thanks @Loamhoof.Actually i'd tried both the versions before posting the issue.
string = string.replace(/(<br \/>)+$| +$/g,'').replace(/^(<br \/>)+|^ +/g,'')
and
string = string.replace(/((<br \/>)| )+$/g,'').replace(/^((<br \/>)| )+/g,'').
Actually what you're suggesting was my first choice. Don't why it didn't work then. :-/

Comment: This is because you forgot you had spaces before your `br`. So, try `string.replace(/(< br \/>| )+$/g,'').replace(/^(< br \/>| )+/g,'')`.

Comment: I don't have spaces before br. It's the HTML line-break tag. When I was posting this, <br />s were being converted into line-breaks. :/
so I'd to do this way..

Comment: Oh so I'm out of idea, I tested it and it worked for me :p Well anyway your problem is still solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
> var string = "< br /> < br />< br />< br /> < br /> < br /> Hello < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> <br />";
> string.replace(/^(<\s*br\s*\/>|\s*)*|(<\s*br\s*\/>|\s)*$/gi, '');
"Hello"
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great. Can you please explain why you preferred string.replace(/^(<\s*br\s*\/>|\s*)*|(<\s*br\s*\/>|\s)*$/gi, ''); over string.replace(/^(<\s*br\s*\/>|\s*)+|(<\s*br\s*\/>|\s)+$/gi, ''); – Rajat Sinha 27 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. I think this should help you,

```
var a="< br /> < br />< br />< br /> < br /> <br /> Hello < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br /> < br />";
var b=a.replace(/< br \/>|\s/g,"");
alert(b);//Hello
```

Cheers...!!!!!